# How to listen to standard in and a socket on the same thread in C#?

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm trying to make a networked console based application, but it needs to be able to listen to standard input and input from a socket at the same time. In C++ I would use the posix select() function to do this, but in C# it appears that [the equivalent select function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.select.aspx) is for sockets only. Is there a way I can listen to both inputs in C# without resorting to multiple threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wait on multiple inputs, you need a WaitHandle for each one, and then you call the static method [WaitHandle.WaitAny](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdykks7z.aspx).

But another option is to use async IO. Use the `BeginXXXX` to start read/receive operations. You supply a callback in each case which will be executed on completion. After you launch them, you wait on a monitor object, and in the callbacks you pulse that monitor object to notify completion. This is a very efficient form of multi-threading programming but you don't have to start any threads explicitly.

To get a raw Stream for standard input, use [Console.OpenStandardInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx55zca2.aspx).

Comment: This seems to be a good solution, and I see how to do it with a network stream, but how would I do the same thing with standard in?

Answer (score 0):

I will start by saying that- no, you can not use `Select()` for StandardInput.

But, `C#` gives you a better way to listen to few I\O.

The `async\await` is a better way, because it lets to avoid blocking at all, even for the calling function.

In the following example, the program listening to the StandardInput `with ReadAsync()`, and in the meantime the PrintStaff() function prints the variable `i` to the console every 3 seconds.

## example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace AsyncExplore
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ReadFromConsole();
            PrintStaff();
        }

        private static void PrintStaff()
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                Console.WriteLine(i++);
            }
        }

        private static async void ReadFromConsole()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4000];
                
                using Stream stdin = Console.OpenStandardInput();
                {
                //read from StandardInput without blocking, so the
                //control yields to Main,
                //and another function can run.
                    int numBytes = await stdin.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 
                        buffer.Length);
                    
                }
                //convert the bytes[] to string
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The advantages are

- Readabilty: you can read the sequence easily.
- Coding: The coding process is much more intuitive and close to the synchronous way.
- Zero-threaded: You can run this Main as a "Listener" without the need of new thread. Unlike Select(), which requires you to stay blocked on Select(), here you can set the whole function as asynchronous, thus returning the control to caller method.

**Note**: In the example, Main() is not `async`, to simplify things, so it get "blocked" in the `while` loop. But you can make `PrintStaff()` async as well, and so the main, and `await` on PrintStaff(). In this case you are perfectly un-blocking the thread.